# Self-adjoint operator with pure point spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that A is a self-adjoint (possible unbounded) operator from a separable Hilbert space H to itself. I would like to know if the following statement is true:

A has pure point spectrum (i.e., the continuous spectrum of A is empty) if and only if the set of eigenvectors of A is complete (in other words, there is an orthonormal basis of H whose elements are eigenvectors of A).

I know that this result is true if A is self-adjoint and compact, but I would like to know if it holds for the class of second-order differential operators that typically appear in quantum mechanics.

Comment: The operator $A:\ell_2\to\ell_2$ defined by $A(x_n)=(x_n/n)$ is compact, self-adjoint, has  an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors (the unit vector basis $(e_i)$), but $0$ is in the continuous spectrum of $A$.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I think your question would have been better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/ , though.

Comment: @M.González: I don't think this is what the OP means by "continuous spectrum" (a vector is in the subspace corresponding to continuous spectrum if its spectral measure is a continuous measure on $\mathbb R$ (= has no atoms)). What you call continuous spectrum is more commonly referred to as "essential spectrum".

Comment: @Christian Remling: For me, $z$ in the continuous spectrum of $A$ means $A-zI$ injective with proper dense range.

Comment: @M.Gonzalez: Since $R(A-t)^{\perp}=N(A-t)$ for $t\in\mathbb R$, this last condition repeats the first one, so this set is $\sigma(A)\setminus\sigma_p(A)$ (with $\sigma_p$ denoting the eigenvalues), and it's not even a spectrum (closed) in general.

Comment: @Christian Remling: If $H$ is the orthogonal sum $L_2(-1,1)\oplus \mathcal{C}$ and  $A(f(t),z)= (tf(t),0)$, which is the continuous spectrum of $A$?

Comment: @M.González: In that case $\sigma_{ac}=\sigma_{cont}=\sigma_{ess}=\sigma=[-1,1]$, $\sigma_{pp}=\{ 0\}$.